# Connecting a JavaScript post API to a Html Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Just need a bit of help connecting the following JavaScript to a HTML form so that I will be able to POST to the below API.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({"email":"someone@example.com","first_name":"Phill","last_name":"Chill"});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/webinars/{webinarId}/registrants',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}', 
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Thanks so much

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I connect this API to an HTML form? I.e. what is the html code that I would need to create a form that will post to this API. Thanks. Sorry for my Ignorance

Answer (score 0):

If you want fill the HTML form with post data recived, you need link the input with the data with ids, something like that:

```
<input id="first-name">
```

The JS to asign the value:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = response.data.first_name;
```

Or if you use jQuery

```
$('#first-name').val(response.data.first_name);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for answering. really appreciate it. I need to POST data to the API above, how would I go about doing that? Thanks

Comment: You can catch the answer data from old API POST, fill the inputs and send data to the URL new API. I hope I can help you, I don't really understand what you want to do

Comment: can you create a working example. don't seem to understand how the above is going to post to the zoom server

Comment: Sorry for time, here is the fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/krake/z5vcwpbL/19/](https://jsfiddle.net/krake/z5vcwpbL/19/)